# Comparing a `tf.constant` to an integer

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I have a `tf.while_loop`, where the `body` argument is defined as the following function:

```
def loop_body(step_num, x):
    if step_num == 0:
        x += 1
    else:
        x += 2
    step_num = tf.add(step_num, 1)
    return step_num, x
```

The problem is that the line `step_num == 0` is never `True`, even though the initial value of `step_num` is `0`. I am assuming that this is because `step_num` is not an integer, but in fact, a `tf.constant` which was defined outside the loop: `step_num = tf.constant(0)`. So I am comparing a `tf.constant` to a Python integer, which will be `False`.

What should I use instead for this comparison?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Assuming `step_num` is the number of training steps you did (i.e., a global step), thien it is a `tf.Variable`, not a constant. Either way, it won't compare to an integer. You can, however, get the value of it as additional output of a `sess.run()` ad use *that* (which is an integer) for the comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First approach: using `tf.cond`:

```
def loop_body(step_num, x):
    x = tf.cond(tf.equal(step_num,0),lambda :x+1,lambda :x+2)
    step_num = tf.add(step_num, 1)
    return step_num, x
```

Second approach: using `autograph`:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import autograph as ag
ag.to_graph(loop_body2)(step_num, x)
```

An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import autograph as ag

def loop_body(step_num, x):
    x = tf.cond(tf.equal(step_num,0),lambda :x+1,lambda :x+2)
    step_num = tf.add(step_num, 1)
    return step_num, x

def loop_body2(step_num, x):
    if step_num == 0:
        x += 1
    else:
        x += 2
    step_num = tf.add(step_num, 1)
    return step_num, x

step_num = tf.constant(0)
x = tf.constant(2)
result1 = loop_body(step_num, x)
result2 = ag.to_graph(loop_body2)(step_num, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result1))
    print(sess.run(result2))

#print 
(1, 3)
(1, 3)
```